# bemapiset.h missing when Visual Studio compiles cpp file

Tags: c++, visual-studio

18>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.14393.0\um\winbase.h(55): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'bemapiset.h': No such file or directory (compiling cpp)

I have reinstalled the SDK and repaired Visual Studio 2015. But the file is still missing, anyone know how to fix the issue?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Seems like that header is part of the Windows 8 SDK, but is not present for Windows 10. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c089302e-c3ad-43f9-b89a-f20f46b4b4ab/windows-sdk-100102400-missing-file-bemapiseth?forum=windowssdk

Comment: Thanks, I have read that post too, and I reinstall SDK 10 and 8.1, but the file is still missing. should I claim a path for VS?